# Category permalinks not built correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I have the following permalink structure for the articles:
/a/%post-id%/%postname%/

I also have installed yoast seo plugin.

The problem I have is the links for the category are built this way
/a/category-name wich is a 404 error. The correct link should be /category-name

I have no idea why this is happening and why the link is being generated with kind of a param of the permalink of the posts (/a/).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the permalink settings page, you can define a permalink structure for category too, enter the same as for your posts:

%category%

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks